# How to recover index of column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

```
Sub Bouton7()

    Dim Derniere_ligne As Long
    Dim ligne_en_cours As Long
    Dim libelle As String

    Derniere_ligne = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
For ligne_en_cours = 2 To Derniere_ligne

    libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 5).Value


    If libelle = "XY" Then
     Rows(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 4     'this will change colour for whole row
End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Here I color line when  `libelle = "XY`

But I would like to replace   `libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, 5).Value`

per  `libelle = Cells(ligne_en_cours, index (CODE_LIBELLE) ).Value`

Because in my table, `CODE_LIBELLE` is the 5th column, so I would like to recover the index of the name of column.

Thanks

ps :

I did that to recover index column of code libelle :

```
Derniere_ligne = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Set ws = Sheets("Feuil4")

For c = 1 To 6
rec = ws.Cells(1, c).Value
If rec = "CODE_LIBELLE" Then
rec2 = c

End If

Next c
```

but my c is always the end of my loop and not the value of rec2

Comment: You will have to scan the headers to find the index yourself (loop/match/find). There is no way to get the "index" of a column using only its "header" name since that's not really a "header", it's just the first row.

Comment: I tried to search but I don't find how to recover value of line and column to have my code libelle

Comment: Use a named range for that header cell.. Then reference the column number by `Range("Your RangeName").Columns.Column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub Bouton7()
    Dim Derniere_ligne As Long
    Dim ligne_en_cours As Long
    Dim libelle As String, m, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or whatever
    
    'locate the header position in Row1
    m = Application.Match("CODE_LIBELLE", ws.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsError(m) Then    'm will be an error value if no match
        MsgBox "Required header not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For ligne_en_cours = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(ligne_en_cours, m).Value = "XY" Then
            ws.Rows(ligne_en_cours).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: Your posted loop is fine, but you would be using `rec2` for the column position and not `c`:

```vb
Set ws = Sheets("Feuil4")

For c = 1 To 6
    rec = ws.Cells(1, c).Value
    If rec = "CODE_LIBELLE" Then
        rec2 = c
        Exit For 'no need to check further so jump out of the loop...
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: perfect, it works !! thanks,  I tried to do it but id didn't work , could you explain where was my error pls ( I edit my post)